# Can we make a Validation Class (or design a certain Structure) that can be shared between Client & Server in GWT?

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform, gwtp

Here is my Gwt Problem. Say, I got a form that has email, firstName, username, password... Textboxes & a submit Button. When users click Submit, the client will validate all fields, after all fields are ok, then they will be sent to Server for another **EXACTLY** same validation.

Someone suggested me to make a Utility class & put that class into the **shared** package.

Look at this code

In my.com.client package:

```
import my.com.shared.Utility;    

public class CustPresenter extends
    Presenter<CustPresenter.MyView, CustPresenter.MyProxy> {



  @Inject DispatchAsync dispatchAsync;


  public void postData(){
     PostData postDataAction=new PostData();
     String fName=fNameTextBox.getText();
     String lName=lNameTextBox.getText();
     //....... more field here ....//
     if(!Utility.isOKString(fName)){
        MyDialogBox myD=new MyDialogBox(fName, "Not OK");
     }
     else if (!Utility.isOKString(lName)){
        MyDialogBox myD=new MyDialogBox(lName, "Not OK");
     }
     ///.......more checking here//

    postDataAction.setFName(fName);
    postDataAction.setFName(lName);
    //... more setting here...// 
     dispatchAsync.execute(postDataAction, postDataCallback);

 }

 private AsyncCallback<PostDataResult> postDataCallback=new AsyncCallback<PostDataResult>(){

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(PostDataResult result) {
         String resultStr=result.getResult();
         if(resultStr.equals("fName is not OK")){
             MyDialogBox myD=new MyDialogBox(fName, "Not OK");
         }
         else if (resultStr.equals("lName is not OK")){
             MyDialogBox myD=new MyDialogBox(lName, "Not OK");
         }
         /// more displaying err message...
    }
   };
}
```

in my.com.server package

```
import my.com.shared.Utility;
public class PostDataActionHandler implements
        ActionHandler<PostData, PostDataResult> {
    @Override
    public PostDataResult execute(PostData action, ExecutionContext context)
            throws ActionException {
        String fName=action.getFName();
        String lName=action.getLName();
        //more geting here....//
        String resultInfo="";
        if(!Utility.isOKString(fName)){
              resultInfo="fName is not OK";
        }
        else if (!Utility.isOKString(lName)){
              resultInfo="lName is not OK";
        }
       ////... more checking here///
        else{
            postData();
        }
        return new PostDataResult(resultInfo);
    }

}
```

As you can see in this structure, even I used Utility in shared package, i still have to validate the same data 3 times. And there're a lot of duplicates.

So my question is:

Can we create a certain Validation class (or design a certain Structure) & put that class in shared package & so client & server can use it, so i just need to validate 1 time rather than doing it 3 times like this?

Answer (score 1):

GWT supports JSR-303 Bean Validation through annotations, and the same validations can be used both client-side and server-side. See the [validation section of the GWT doc](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideValidation.html).

Comment: i still have to check at client + server side. But for my question, i am looking for s Structure or a Design that both client & server can share the same Validation class. That class can accept data from Client & Server & do some checking, & return a result that can be passed into client or server.

Comment: You have to check at client + server, but it is the same validation code for both.

Comment: @Min Hai this is the right answer. Please investigate JSR-303 validation.

Comment: I only have 10,20 simple fields to check why need some extra package? i hate extra package cos it require a lot of config headache & if i am not doing right then it waste of time. If i am doing right then i need to learn how to use it & that is another headache & it costs time to learn. I program at home, there no one to help.

Comment: JSR-303 is going to require some configuration, but it's the way that will require the less code. If you want to roll your own shared (client and server) validation classes, you can, but it's gonna require a lot of code. However, I strongly recommend that you use David's advice. GWT gives you tools like client-side validation using JSR-303 annotations on your POJOs. You can combine the validation framework with GWT Editors for powerful form validation. On the server side, some frameworks like RestEasy will handle JSR-303 validation automatically for you.